# how to see the celery messages in redis?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have a celery worker running redis as a broker.
Starting the worker processes gives me this:

```
 celery -A celeryworker worker --loglevel=INFO
 
 -------------- celery@cd38f5e26c28 v5.2.1 (dawn-chorus)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-5.10.25-linuxkit-x86_64-with-glibc2.28 2021-12-14 00:22:02
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myapp:0x7f96dd51af10
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis-container:6379/1
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 6 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> 0                exchange=0(direct) key=0
                

[tasks]
  . app.tasks.bye
  . app.tasks.printme

[2021-12-14 00:22:02,708: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis-container:6379/1
[2021-12-14 00:22:02,717: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-12-14 00:22:03,740: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone


[2021-12-14 00:22:03,762: INFO/MainProcess] celery@cd38f5e26c28 ready.
[2021-12-14 00:22:23,332: INFO/MainProcess] Task app.task.bye[7e28e6a0-8aaa-4609-bd85-9312e91cb355] received
[2021-12-14 00:23:23,326: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task app.tasks.bye[7e28e6a0-8aaa-4609-bd85-9312e91cb355] succeeded in 60.061842500006605s: 'the text was byebye!!'
```

This is what I can see in redis right after starting the celery workers:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
1) "_kombu.binding.0"
2) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
3) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
```

Even if I set a long timer on my tasks (`sleep(60)`) the tasks will take 60 seconds to run, but I still don't see anything in my redis container.
`mget <key>` returns `nil` for all keys above.

I was expecting to see messages incoming in form of ID or something into Redis (I can see messages if I use SQS as broker, but not for redis).

Comment: I believe the messages are fleeting and short-lived. Once the worker picks the job up, I believe the messages go away. Then it'll take however long for the results to be stored in Redis, if you chose to store results in that kind of backend. This is a good question IMO, but I have not found an answer for it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your messages are picked immediately by your worker.
To actually see where redis stores them, do this:

1. stop your worker process - so that messages won't get popped from redis
2. Open python shell and execute the task - `task.delay(*args, **kwargs)`

You'll find your messages under `celery` key in your redis:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys * 
1) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
2) "_kombu.binding.celery"
3) "celery" 
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> LLEN celery 
(integer) 1 
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> LINDEX celery 0
"{\"body\": \"XXXXXXXX\", \"headers\": {}, \"content-type\": \"application/x-python-serialize\", ...}\"
```

Check your celery broker url and see which [logical database](https://redis.io/commands/select/) it is using